# Deserialize json request error - unexpected character

Tags: json, rest

I am getting this error when trying to deserialize an HTTP response - hope you can help:

> FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('<' (code
>   60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true',
>   'false' or 'null') at input location [2,2]

Very quickly, I am doing a POC on connecting two Salesforce orgs via REST. I have created a super simple REST service in a sandbox and am now trying to call it from a different sandbox. I am able to connect, but how do I deserialize the response get - the access token - and call my REST service?

This is my code - I just call it through execute anonymous for now:
 String accessToken;
String sfdcInstanceURL;

```
try{
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(ENP_POINT_URL);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD);
    String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
    req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
    req.setBody(String.format(REQUEST_BODY ,new string[]{CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                                         USERNAME,PASSWORD}));
    req.setTimeout(60000);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse hRes = http.send(req);

    Map<String, String> results = (Map<String, String>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(hRes.getBody());
    //Map<String,String> res = (Map<String,String>) JSON.deserialize(hRes.getBody(),Map<String,String>.class);

    accessToken = results.get('oauth_token');
    sfdcInstanceURL = results.get('loginURL');

    System.debug('Response1: ' + hres.getBody());
    System.debug('Response1: ' + hres);

    System.debug('accessToken: ' + accessToken);
    System.debug('sfdcInstanceURL: ' + sfdcInstanceURL);

    req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(ENP_POINT_URL2);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    req.setBody('{"name":"mighty moose"}');

    //System.debug('Response3: ' + res.getBody());
    //System.debug('Response3: ' + res);     

    //OAuth objAuthenticationInfo = (OAuth)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(), OAuth.class);
    //return objAuthenticationInfo;
}catch(CallOutException ce){
    throw ce;
}
```

This is the response body:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please paste the response body as text in your question. Based on your screenshot, it appears that it is not JSON.

Comment: Hi David, can you direct me how to do that. If I remove the line that returns the error and I System.debug the responce.getBody(), the above is what I get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error typically happens when the call you are making returns an error page that is HTML rather than JSON. `System.debug` the string before trying to deserialize to see what is going on.

Comment: Hi Keith, I have pasted the response in the question above - can you help me debug this? I have no clue on how to proceed.

Comment: @user2936057 That looks like a login page, so you have not successfully authenticated before making the request.

Comment: Hi Keith, this is the authentication request... So you are saying that the authentication didn't work. Why do I get status OK - status code 200 then? Can you help me debug and understand the issue?

Comment: @user2936057 There are a number of choices on how to authenticate and holding/sending the username/password is probably the weakest approach so not something to invest a lot of time in. I don't know if the approach you are using can be made to work; appending the security token to the password might help. But I suggest you choose the most appropriate one of these [Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm) approaches instead as they are well documented (though a little puzzling at first).

Comment: Hi Keith, I will try to connect with Named Credentials instead - although I am bit reluctant to leave my approach without it working, since I really just wanted to use this for some testing.

You do not have any ideas on what could be wrong on the example above? Thx.

Comment: @user2936057 Not immediately.

Comment: Apologize for the late comment - Selected as best answer as I could not get the setup to work like this and opted to change the approach. A namedcredential seems to fit my purpose and have followed this line instead.

Comment: @MR.M. No problem; glad you found a solution.